# Loop through nested dataLayer array to return pipe delimited strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have a nested dataLayer variable on our booking platform. Users can make one or multiple variables are we want to pull out a string containing each of the product types contained within the array. I am hitting a error when debugging this however.

The location of the variable I would like to collect is:

dataLayer.booking.products[i].travelType

```
try{
  var productList = {};
  for(i=0;i<dataLayer.booking.products.length;i++){
    productList[dataLayer.booking.products[i].travelType];
  }
  return productList.join('|');
}
catch(err){}
```

I am naive with JS so I apologies for a basic question.

[image]

M

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It looks like you're setting `productList[key]` without defining a value. Since this is an Object (dictionary, map, etc) you'd want to at least do something like `productList[key] = true`. Further still, your code can be quite simplified if all you're wanting to do is pull those values and actually put into an *array* of strings, as opposed to a map. I'll post an answer showing this.

Comment: Your `productlist` is defined as object and object don't have join method

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser - thanks so much, this works a treat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shows that you're setting a new property of the object `productList`, but you're not defining a value, e.g. `{foo: }` instead of `{foo: "bar"}`. It looks like what you want is an *array* that you can add strings to. For example:

```
var productList = dataLayer.booking.products.map(function(product) {
    return product.travelType;
});

return productList.join('|');
```

Note that this is using the [Array's `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method as opposed to your `for` loop. You could also define `productList` as an array in a previous line, and then use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method on the `products` Array to loop through every item, but I think this is cleaner and still legible. You can reduce the code further with ES6 syntax, but for your question it's probably better to show code that is more clearly defined.